# Andrid application exit

Tags: java, android

I write my first Mobil application and i can't find out why my application go in to the else part of the code.
This part is the login.java and i don't no what is the problem wiht this.
Pls help me some one.

The Result is what i got from the data base and it contains a nunber if the user can login is successfully.

```
                                if (result=="K1") {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adat[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else if (result=="K2") {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adat[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else if (result=="K3"){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adat[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{

                                    //int ID = ;
                                    //String ID = result;
                                    felhasznalo_segedlet Felhasznalo_segedlet = new felhasznalo_segedlet(Integer.parseInt(result), data[0]);
                                    sessionsegedletek sessionsegedletek = new sessionsegedletek(belepes.this);
                                    sessionsegedletek.mentesSession(Felhasznalo_segedlet);

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sikeres bejelentkezés "+data[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    finish();
                                    ActivityMozgato();
                                }
```

Comment: You can't compare String using == operator. You should use String.equals() instead

Comment: To follow on from what @from56 said-  == doesn't check if two strings are the same text, it checks if they're the same object-  the same reference.  The equals() function checks the data of the string.  This goes for every object in Java.

Comment: finish(); remove

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `==` operator for string value comparison, you should use `result.equals()` for comparing strings.

```
if(result.equals('K1')){
 // your code
}
```